# Set variables declared through let* as ignorable

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, let, lexical-scope, unused-variables

I am trying to write a macro that would generate code that looks like:

```
(defun test ()
    (let* ((_ (exp1))
           (_ (exp2))
           ...
           (_ (expn)))))
```

The `(expn)` calls might be called purely due to their side effects, and it is possible that their return value (stored in `_`) will never be used. This leads SBCL to emit an style warning: `The variable _ is defined but never used.`

How can I prevent this warning? I tried declaring the variable as ignorable (through `(declare (ignorable _))`) in various places in the code but that doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't care about the return values, why not `(progn (exp1) (exp2) ... )`?

Comment: @teapot418 Because the real macro does something a lot more complex, I have simply given a minimal example to clarify the question. 

Basically, I am trying to create an alternative to `progn` that allows declaring variables in the middle using `(var x 1)` form.

Comment: Someone's been reading the recent Hacker News thread on a lisp book.

Comment: @Shawn Someone was pointing this problem out, and decided to solve it for himself instead of fighting with strangers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to do and is a somewhat unclear part of the CL standard.  In particular in a case like

```
(let ((foo 1)
      (foo 2))
  (declare ... involving foo ...)
  ...)
```

Which `foo` does the declaration apply to?  Or does it apply to all of them?

There have been discussions about this and I forget the conclusion.  I am fairly sure different implementations differ.  In the case where you are generating this `let*` form with a macro then the answer is to not do that, but instead generate a set of nested `let` forms with appropriate declarations.

Answer (score 2):

As a solution, you could try something like this :

```
(defun test ()
  (let* ((_ (exp1))
         (_ (progn _ (exp2)))
         (_ (progn _ (expn))))
    _))
```

which does not generate any warning. After the last `_`, you could add the body of the function.

Comment: I like this solution, but it would be problematic if the output of any `expn` was a lambda that had some side-effects, which would then get run on the next `progn`. Thanks for the hint though, it might be useful elsewhere.

Comment: @marked-off-topic merely referring to a variable binding cannot cause side effects: it would need to be a symbol macro or something like that.  However I'd much rather create code which is explicitly says 'ignore this' rather than code which is trying to fool the compiler.  Eapecially since the compiler could be smart enough to work out this is not actually a reference!